# PHP: How to print row of multidimensional array with conditions

Tags: php, arrays, sqlsrv

I'm a PHP beginner. I would like to print rows based on specific condition. For Example, I have a set of Data from SQL-Query(shown below) and I want to print all rows of [Series no] only when Type = 210 and Category = J. I know 'foreach' loop should be used in this case, but I do not know how.

[image: Table from SQL-Query]

And this is what I've tried. I know it is wrong but as I said I am a beginner and self learning.

```
$get_data = sqlsrv_query($connde, $mainquery);

$data_array = [];
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_data, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data_array[$row["Type"]][$row["Category"]][$row["Series No"]][$row["End Date"]];
}


foreach ($data_array as $value1) {
    if ($value1 = 210) {
        foreach ($value1 as $value2) {
            if isset($value2 == 'J')
            echo "<td>" . $row["Series No"] . "</td>";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The line in your `while` is not doing anything, do you want to assign it to some var?

Comment: `$value1 = 210` assigns the number, you want `$value1 == 210` to compare

Comment: `SELECT * FROM SeriesNo WHERE Type = 235 AND Category = 'J'` Then you just print everything that comes back, no need to filter in your loop.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes, i do but that's for another case.

Comment: @brombeer Yes, but $value1=210 wont work either.

Comment: @dazed-and-confused Yes. But unfortunately that is not the solution I'm looking for because I wanted to print other data from the same query as well.

Comment: Ok, then as @AbraCadaver mentioned above. Your `while` loop is doing nothing. @brombeer's comment about your `if` needs to be corrected as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deal with the rows directly:

```
<?php
$mainquery = 'SELECT `Type`, `Category`, `Series No`, `End Date` FROM `Foo`'; 
$get_data  = sqlsrv_query($connde, $mainquery);

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_data, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if($row['Type'] == 210 && $row['Category'] == 'J') {
        echo "<td>" . $row['Series No'] . "</td>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg! Perfect! Thank you :) Never thought that it is that simple!

Comment: Else if you need the rows for later, or you are passing the data around assign to another array:  `$data[] = $row;`

Comment: if I assign another array like you said : `$data[ ]= $row`, how do i define the function later? Can I still use `if($row['Type'] == 210 && $row['Category'] == 'J')`? or do i need something else?

Comment: @anis I only mentioned it, because sometimes data is passed through to views, or from one function to another.  You'd just loop the $data as if it were rows.

Comment: I get the idea that something like that was your intention, but the body of your posted while loop is confused.